# Why is the following Haskell code hanging?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell. I was trying to solve the diophantine equation *|x^y-y^x| is prime*, using Haskell, for a given upper bound *x, y < n*.

So, I wrote this Haskell code:

```
-- list of primes
listprimesupto :: Integral a => a -> [a]
listprimesupto 1 = []
listprimesupto 2 = [2]
listprimesupto n = let halflstprimes = (listprimesupto (n `div` 2))
                   in halflstprimes++[i|i<-[((n `div` 2)+1)..n], (length [x|x<-halflstprimes, (i `mod` x) == 0])==0 ]

-- is prime?
is_prime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
is_prime 1 = False
is_prime n = let halflstprimes = (listprimesupto (n `div` 2))
             in (length [x|x<-halflstprimes, (n `mod` x) == 0])==0           

-- solve |x^y - y^x| == prime
xy_yx_p :: Integral t => t -> [(t, t)]
--xy_yx_p n = [(x,y)|x<-[2..n], y<-[2..n], x < y, (abs (x^y-y^x)) `elem` (listprimesupto (n^3))] -- version 1, works but upper limit too small
xy_yx_p n = [(x,y)|x<-[2..n], y<-[2..n], x < y, (let t=abs (x^y-y^x) in is_prime t)==True] -- version 2, hangs for n>3 ...
```

`xy_yx_p n` (version 2, uncommented) hangs for *n* > 3, in GHCi. Ctrl-C doesn't even work. I have to kill `ghc` from Activity Monitor (I'm on Mac).

Any idea what am I doing wrong in `xy_yx_p`? The other two functions seem to work fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: you can easily simplify to `[(x,y) | x <- [2..n], y <- [(x+1)..n], is_prime (abs (x^y - y^x))]`. See how it's never useful to say `== True`?

Comment: Note that `length [x | x <- xs, p x] == 0` can be written much nicer, and lazily, as `all (not . p) xs`

Comment: @Cactus: And that's much more efficient, as it will break on the first element, whereas `length xs` will have to wait for the whole computation (unless that's a custom `length :: Foldable t => t -> Peano` or similar).

Comment: Yes, which is what I meant by lazily. But you're right in stressing that it is short-circuiting.

Comment: @dfeuer: yes, I tried that. The reason I made the expression so boringly explicit is because I wanted to make sure I have the semantic correct. But, in its initial form, it looked like you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: @Cactus: oh, that's cool. Thank you.

Comment: @Zeta: thanks for the efficiency suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

So, if it hangs for `n = 4`, what's so special about that case? Well, it's `t`. For `x = 2` and `y = 4`, you will get

```
t = abs (2 ^ 4 - 4 ^ 2)
  = abs (16    - 16   )
  = abs 0
  = 0
```

Therefore, you use `0` in `is_prime`, and thereby also in `listprimesupto`. This leads to a never ending recursion:

```
listprimesupto 0 = let halflstprimes = (listprimesupto (0 `div` 2))
                   in -- .....
```

So make sure that you handle non-positive inputs:

```
listprimesupto n | n <= 0 = []

is_prime n | n <= 1 = False
```

Comment: `5` shouldn't hang if you used the techniques described above. But the other will take a ___very___ long time, since you're calculating the same lists over and over. And for `10`, you're needing the primes up to `2486784401 = 10^9 - 9^10`. That's going to take a while.

Comment: I realized now that n=4 hanging triggers anything above 5 hanging. Because the case 2^4-4^2 gets tested before k^m-m^k, for any k>2 and m>4. So, yes, you're right t=0 is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: About the calculation taking too long: yes I expected that. Also memory consumption was expected to become very large because (at least my understanding was that) Integral types can go to integers as large as memory can hold them. Which was one reason I picked Haskell for this problem.

Comment: `Integral` just means integer-like.  It's the specific type `Integer` that can grow arbitrarily large.